# Space and tab need to be used in expressions, but are ignored on parsing

Tags: parsing, haskell

I have this code:

```
module Parser where

-- begin: major parsing function

infixr 5 >*>

type Parse a b = [a] -> [(b,[a])]
```

I am trying to make a function that will parse expressions from a file and let the whitespace and tabs be used in an expression, but not parsed and I am running into a brick wall. My function I know should look something like this:

```
parser :: Parse Char Expr
parser = litParse `alt` (varParse `alt` opExpParse)
```

But its not doing what I want it to do.

Comment: More details please. How have you defined `alt` (perhaps you didn't realize that you have to write `alt` yourself)

Comment: "It's not doing what I want it to do" is rather vague. Without seeing the complete definition for the code you currently have, and what results you actually get, we can't meaningfully comment.